# Time integral over stochastic process depends on distribution only?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $X(t),Y(t)$ be two stochastic processes, integrable on $[0,T]$ with $X(t)\stackrel{d}{=}Y(t),\forall t\in [0,T]$.

Does this imply

$$\int_0^t X(s)ds = \int_0^t Y(s)ds, \qquad \forall t \in [0,T],$$

i.e. the integral depends on the distribution only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not. To see why, try $X(t)=U$ for every $t$, $Y(t)=U$ for every $t\leqslant\frac12T$ and $Y(t)=V$ for every $t\gt\frac12T$, for some nondegenerate i.i.d. $U$ and $V$, then $X(T)=T\cdot U$ is not in general distributed like $Y(T)=\frac12T\cdot (U+V)$.

Comment: Thanks! The reason I'm asking is that I'm trying to handle $\int_0^1 e^{-t/2} B(e^t)dt$ and was hoping to use the scaling property of BM. Well, can I instead scale the time as I want, so just apply the integrand transformation $t=log(x)$ to get $\int_0^1 e^{-t/2} B(e^t)dt = \int_1^e x^{-3/2} B(x)dx$?

Comment: Of course. This is just the ordinary integral of a continuous function on a compact interval and the change of variable $t=\log x$ is $C^1$ so everything is fine (and deterministic, really). Honestly I do not see a iota of relation between this new problem and your question.